# How to use Ternary operator when the expression is only true?

Tags: c#

I have a problem when wanting to use the **ternary operator** in a **ForEach extension**. My code is as follows:

```
List<string> lstText = new List<string>();
lstComboBox.ForEach(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Text) ? lstText.Add(x.Text));
```

I need to use the ternary operator to validate that there is a text comboBox and then save it to the list, if you do not find something, does nothing.

Comment: Why do you *need* to use a ternary operator, why not just use a simple `if()` statement?

Comment: "I need to use the ternary operator" -- No, you don't. I'm sure you've seen the `if` keyword before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I need to use the ternary operator to validate that there is a text comboBox and then save it to the list, if you do not find something, does nothing.

Don't do that. It's terrible style, hard to reason about, and contrary to common practice.

Do this:

```
var result = comboBox
             .Select(comboBoxItem => comboBoxItem.Text)
             .Where(text => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
             .ToList();
```

You have three logical operations: get the text out of the combo box, filter out the blank text, create a list.  This program very clearly does those three things. Don't mess around with loops and ternaries and adding things to lists unless you need to; write the program at the level that expresses *what you are trying to do* and not *how you are doing it*.

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you Eric.

Comment: That excellent response. Thanks for teaching me, I'm just an apprentice.

Comment: @Richard: You are welcome. Something that will help in the future is to phrase your questions in terms of what you are trying to do. Many beginners get off onto a wrong path early and then ask a lot of questions about how to stay on that wrong path. Better to get on the right path in the first place.